# How can I find all the subfields of Q?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Is there a way to express any generic sub-field of the rationals?

I know that all the subRING of Z is all the set of integer multiples for all natural numbers.

Is there a similar situation with the rationals and sub-fields of the rationals?

Comment: Your definition of ring includes having a unit element?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ has no nontrivial subfields.

Comment: How do you know this?

Answer (score 12):

just to detail the answers already given, note that any subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$ must contain the identity, hence it must contain $\mathbb{Z}$. since a subfield contains the inverse of any non-zero element, it must contain $\{\frac1{n}; n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. thus it must contain $\frac{m}{n}$ for any non-zero integers $m,n$

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is a *prime field*, that is, a field generated by $1$. As such, it has no nontrivial subfields.